# (Win XP) setting up tray application to run before the logon screen

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-xp, screen

I would like to run a software before the windows logon screen, this software installs a small tray icon near the system's clock on the taskbar.

The service was created using sc.exe, and was able to check if it's active and set to run automatically whenever the system starts.

The service is there, but when I reboot the computer, it doesn't seem to be active for some reason.

I've tried to run the service manually but it seems to be timing out, and it won't run. If I login and run it manually, no problems: the tray icon shows up.

Could this be because of the fact that at the logon moment, there's no tray bar?

The command I've used to create the service is this:

sc.exe create "KVMDevice" start= "auto" binPath= "c:...."

Many thanks, 
Vlad

Comment: The notification area is per-user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Before the "logon moment", there is NO Desktop associated with the interactive user (who has not logged yet), thus not tray bar.
2. When creating a service that should show some message to the user, be sure that you configure your service as "[being capable to interact with the desktop](http://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/)"

Comment: Configuring a service to interact with the desktop is actually not recommanded and has changed since XP. But, since you mentionned XP, I still mentioned this configuration setting.

Comment: I'm wondering, if there's no taskbar, can I do something so the process will still run?

Comment: Actually, here's the general idea. You know how VNC server runs in the background, before the user logs in, but there's also a tray icon?

I want to achieve the same thing with this app. Does the success of my actions depend very much on the internals of the app (e.g. the programmers might decide that if there's no tray bar, the app shouldn't terminate and just run in the background as a process), or is there a way to overcome the lack of the taskbar?

Many thanks again,

Comment: thanks for the details. The taskbar (I guess you mean the Tray Notification Area - TNA) is just a kind of logical container that shows some applications running in the background and having a window object in their first thread. Actually, the point is not really if your app is shown or not in the TNA, but the fact that your app should run (and have an UI-feedback) in the background. Does this represents what your needs are?

Comment: Hi @mox, yes that's absolutely correct. So, the question is, how to make sure the application is running, even though no TNA is present. Many thanks, Vlad

Comment: Well, as you did, develop your app as a service, be sure that the configuration are correct (like credentials, interaction with UI, restart options, type of dependencies, startup type..). And then your app starts and runs when the systems has booted.

Comment: The thing is, this is not my app, and I have no control over its internals, is there a workaround?

Comment: If the service is implemented in a DLL you could try to host it in svchost.exe (I must admit that I have never tried this, but in theory, this must be feasible). But, actually, these configurations settings, as far as the Service Control Manager - SCM - is concerned, should take place during the registration of a service (aka. stored in the registry).

Comment: Hi @mox, there is no dll, just an executable. Would using regedit help in any way, rather than me using the services console provided by windows in Control Panel -> Administration tools?

Comment: @Vladimir - you can use reg.exe in a batch (or whatever utility, srcipt, etc.. capable of handling registration tasks).